# Calculate multiple column percentages

Tags: sas, calculated-columns

Consider the following SAS table:

```
data input;             
input Row$ Col1 Col2;       
datalines;              
A 10 20                    
B 20 20                   
C 20 20
;
run;
```

I would like to calculate two further columns - "Col1_col_pct" and "Col2_col_pct" which are the column percentages of the columns "Col1" and "Col2" respectively which would produce the following output table:

```
Row   Col1    Col2    Col1_col_pct    Col2_col_pct
A      10      20         20.00           33.33
B      20      20         40.00           33.33
C      20      20         40.00           33.33
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a code-on-request site, but if you're having problems with a specific approach I'm sure people can advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROC SQL can do it as well, though its still manual:

```
Proc sql;
    create table want as
    select *, 
    col1/sum(col1) as PCT_COL1 format=percent8.2,
    col2/sum(col2) as PCT_COL2 format=percent8.2
    from input;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SUMMARY to calculate the sum of each column and then join it back on to the original.  Calculate your percents then.

```
data input;             
input Row$ Col1 Col2;       
datalines;              
A 10 20                    
B 20 20                   
C 20 20
;
run;

proc summary data=input;
var col1 col2;
output out=sum(drop=_type_ _freq_) sum= /autoname;
run;

data want(drop=col1_sum col2_sum);
set input;
if _n_ = 1 then
    set sum;

Col1_pct = col1 / col1_sum;
col2_pct = col2 / col2_sum;
run;
```